# Optimal use of BufferedWriter for repeated writing of "small' amounts of data in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, bufferedwriter

**Context**

I have a program which needs to store sensor data to a file. The objective is: collect and store this information as fast as possible.

**Program flow**

Currently, I'm doing the following:

- Acquire sensor data in a list (through `Collections.synchronizedList` to be thread-safe)
- If the list exceeds a given threshold (at this moment 10 000 entries), then store that list to a file.

Saving (to a file) happens in a thread to optimise my application performance.

**Question(s)**

So I have the following questions regarding the optimal use of the `BufferedWriter` for my application/use-case:

- Should I use the write method of the `BufferedWriter` when receiving sensor data. And throw away the list.
- Should I close the `BufferedWriter` every time I've written the list to a file? thereby repeatedly opening and closing BufferedWriters (approximately every 10 seconds)?
- Or should I keep the `BufferedWriter` open as long as we listen for sensor data?

**Why this is posted on StackOverflow and not Android Enthusiast**

This is posted on SO because this is a general coding problem, i.e. this is not specific to the Android platform. The issue lies here in the fact that we need to store "small" amounts of data repeatedly without interfering with the rapid data acquisition functions.